# Easiest way to allocate "blank" block of data to .dat file

Tags: c, file-io, binaryfiles, fwrite

Looking for a quick way to allocate a block of data to be managed from disk. I'm allocating a block of 50 structs, and while most of the memory allocates fine, when I read it all back I get junk messages returned in some of the fields that should be blank. I assume this is me allocating the space incorrectly somehow that allows some junk from memory to leak in there.

```
if ((fpBin = fopen(BINARYFILE, "w+b")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open binary file %s.\n", BINARYFILE);
    return;
}
fwrite(fpBin, sizeof(struct student), 50, fpBin); //Write entire hash table to disk
```

struct definition

```
typedef struct student
{
    char firstName[20]; //name
    char lastName[20];
    double amount;  //amount owed
    char stuID[5];   //4 digit code
}student;
```

Is how I was taught, yet I'm still getting some junk in my data instead of it being a clean slate. So question: How do I set all fields to blank?

Answer:

```
student tempStu[50] = {0};
fwrite(tempStu, sizeof(struct student), BUCKETSIZE, fpBin); //Write entire hash table to disk
```

Comment: Please show the student struct definition.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It's irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fwrite(fpBin, sizeof(struct student), 50, fpBin);

You're writing your file pointer, not your student structs, to disk. That first `fpBin` should instead be a pointer to your data. That data can be an array of 50 student structs initialized to 0, perhaps with calloc or by defining it at file scope, but it has to be somewhere. Instead, you are writing 50*sizeof(struct student) bytes from your `fpBin` pointer, which is undefined behavior -- you'll either crash with an access violation or you'll write junk to disk. That junk is what you're getting when you read it back.

Also, using a constant like `50` is bad practice ... it should be a variable (or manifest constant) that holds the number of students that you're writing out.

BTW, on Linux and other POSIX systems, you could allocate a block of zeroes on disk just by writing the last byte (or in some other way making the file that large).

Comment: there are no student structs holding data, the struct is only defined to read and write data from the file.

Comment: @lloyd Sorry, but you're talking nonsense. The data in the file must be read and written from memory somewhere, so there *must* be student structs holding data. `fpBin` points to a file descriptor ... it can't hold a `struct student`. It never ever should be the first argument to fwrite ... if you thought you were taught that, you're mistaken. Even your comment says "Write entire hash table to disk" ... where's that hash table? It's not pointed to by `fpBin`, obviously. So, do you want answers, or are you certain you already have them? If the latter, I'll leave you be.

Comment: @lloyd even if there isn't any data in the structures, you still have to point to a set of 50 `struct student`s, or at least something of an equivalent size.

Comment: @TaylorFlores I edited my answer to refer to student structs initialized to 0. In the question the OP says he allocated a block of 50 structs but now claims there is no such thing ... strange. I took the time to point out his obvious error here, but as a friend says, no good deed goes unpunished.